# Error displaying the digital signature font when using itextsharp on adobe reader

Tags: pdf, itext, adobe-reader, foxit-reader

My digital signature has a font error when opening in Adobe Reader, but when opening a signed pdf with Foxit Reader, it displays normally.

Currently I can use Foxit Reader temporarily, but I am concerned that in the coming time Foxit reader will update to a new version, my PDF will also show font errors.

So I need to completely problem this issue. Does anyone have any experience with this problem? thanks.
I have attached my 2 pdf files link. Inside:

- 1 unsigned PDF
- 1 signed PDF (this is a pdf with font display error)

### [unsign pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eNyE7ihO446AfgqOu6DHQSBs4ne2JSPk/view?usp=sharing)

[signed pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-FFzLcr43HjOHpFnyP3DQpZFE6Ws-lWZ/view?usp=sharing)

[Font display error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQuVs.png)

Comment: It is great that you already shared example pdfs for analysis. What's missing, though, is your pivotal code using itextsharp to sign the document . Without it it's difficult to say what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: I have found a solution to that problem.  using "basefont.subset = false" will solve the problem of font errors when signing on the pdf

Comment: Can you explain what the Basefont "subset" property means? @mkl

Comment: If that `subset` property is true, a collection of actually used glyphs of that font is created during pdf creation, and in the end only the glyphs actually needed, a subset of all the glyphs in the font, are embedded.

Comment: I've had a more thorough look at your signed PDF but couldn't identify the issue in the genuine PDF structure. As I don't really know much about TTF internals, I did not dive into the embedded font program, though. Furthermore, Adobe Reader signals that it has problems with the font used in your signature visualization. Thus, I think there is an issue in that TTF font program. For further analysis please supply enough code to reproduce the issue.